# Is the value on a helmet worth the same on a level 3 helmet than on a level 1 helmet?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

When you get a helmet, it always come with a set Durability id name it. There's a number next to it, I think level 1 is 80, and level 3 is 200. But when you take shots, that number goes down, and when it reaches 0, your helmet is gone.

So when I'm looting somebody, I often wonder... Should I trade, for instance, my level 3 helmet at 70 durability for a level 1 with full 80 durability? Or should I keep the level 3 helmet because the level 3 durability is worth more than level 1 durability?